# Ein Restaurant verlassen, ohne die Rechnung zu begleichen

Tags: idiom, colloquial

Ich meine, es gibt einen umgangssprachlichen Ausdruck dafür, wenn man ein Restaurant verlässt ohne seine Rechnung zu bezahlen.

Es hat irgendwas mit Franzosen zu tun?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wenn man ohne zu bezahlen aus dem Restaurant geht, so spricht man von

> [die Zeche prellen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zechprellerei)

Die Redewendung "mit Franzosen" dagegen wäre

> [sich (auf) französisch verabschieden / empfehlen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sich_auf_franz%C3%B6sisch_empfehlen)

Dies bedeutet, eine gesellschaftliche Veranstaltung zu verlassen, ohne sich vom Gastgeber zu verabschieden. Laut Wikipedia wird dasselbe Verhalten auch anderen Nationalitäten zugeschrieben, z.B. sich *polnisch* oder *holländisch* verabschieden.

Comment: Achso - ich hatte die Frage nicht verstanden. Dank deiner Antwort ist sie jetzt klar :-D

Comment: *sich französisch verabschieden* kenne ich nur als sich (eben) nicht verabschieden. Im Sinne von "Zeche prellen" habe ich das noch nicht gehört (Allerdings liegt es nahe, dass man sich nicht verabschiedet, wenn man nicht bezahlen will...)

Comment: @tofro eben. Ist meine Antwort in diesem Punkt unklar?

Comment: Nein, Stephies Antwort ist perfekt. Ich habe die Frage falsch gestellt, aber deswegen sind wir ja hier, oder? (Ich selbst würde diesen Ausdruck nie verwenden, aber es ist immer gut zu wissen, wovon die Kumpels reden.)  Vielen Dank, Stephie.

Comment: @Stephie - Nein, so wars auch nicht gemeint - Eher als Beipflichten.

Comment: @tofro Danke für die Klarstellung.